# How do i use my own images in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-recognition, tensorflow-datasets

I know this question has been asked before but I haven't been able to find an answer I can work with yet. I'm new to Python and Tensorflow but managed to get my accuracy up to +-99.3% with the MNIST-image set. Now I would like to try to use my own images but this proved to be more difficult to me than expected.

I have read the tutorial page on the Tensorflow site hundreds of times but it just doesn't make sense to me and whatever I try I just end up with warnings. Now I want to figure it out myself but does anyone have an idea which way would be the easiest to work with my own images? Or any examples? I've been looking online for them but it feels like I'm finding 1000's of them but none of them gets explained in a way I can understand.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: To help answer this - what are your images?  How many?  Are they labeled?  What size?  What classes / how many classes? Do you want to do classification, or something more sophisticated?

Comment: I have 42 tokens each with a different symbol on it. The symbols are really stylized so the image size can be really low quality. My goal is to recognize which token I've made a picture of. This means 42 tokens each with a different label.

Comment: Physical tokens that you're taking a picture of in advance to create a labeled dataset?  How many pictures are you willing to take of each under different conditions (background, lighting, orientation, etc.)? :)

Comment: I was planning on roughly 10 pictures each, mostly for different angles and then use code to make at least 10/20 more pictures with changes in contrast and things like that. I guessed that would save me a lot of time.

I was planning on creating a labeled dataset like the MNIST images but I'm not familiar with that format so I have to find another way to do so.

Comment: Oh and i know that that isn't a lot of pictures but my main problem is using my own images within TensorFlow, the generation of more images/taking more photos is another part of the project which I'm not too worried about. With different settings and cutting out parts of the images, centering the symbols on the tokens and stuff like that i could probably make around 100/200 images for each token if that would prove to be necessary for better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so putting this together, you have 42 classes, and expect to have approximately 10 pictures each.

This places you pretty squarely in the need of two things:

- [Transfer Learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)
- [Data Augmentation](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/data-augmentation-techniques-in-cnn-using-tensorflow-371ae43d5be9)

You've already addressed the likely need for data augmentation in the comments, and you're spot on:  In order to make the most of your 10 images per class, you'll want to apply a whole bunch of transformations to them.  Probably many more than 10/20 total images:

- Cropping
- Scaling
- Noise
- Contrast/color/brightness adjustment
- Rotation

A good example of data augmentation for image classification is in the [official resnet example model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/vgg_preprocessing.py)

The second is transfer learning.  When you're trying to learn a model on 42 classes from quite little data, you'll probably be able to do better by starting from a model trained on other data, and then retraining the last (few) layers with your new dataset.  The reasoning behind this is that the much larger example space of the initial training will help your classifier learn a variety of common image features, which your transfer-learned classifier can use to achieve higher-level recognition more quickly.

An alternative, of course, is you could do some form of active learning -- train a classifier, and then show it images of your tokens (perhaps via webcam, classifying each frame), and when it gets one wrong, save that as an example for the next training round.  This takes more work and you'd have to build some infrastructure for it, so I'd start with transfer learning.

You then have the question of what architecture to start with for the transfer learning.  Inception is probably too much for what you're doing, but the stock MNIST model is probably more simple than you want.  You'll need to do some experimentation -- a modified LeNet-style classifier like the common MNIST examples can work pretty well (add another convolutional layer, add batchnorm and maybe a bit of dropout).  Alternatively, you could start with a pretrained [Mobilenet](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/06/mobilenets-open-source-models-for.html) network and transfer learn from it.  I'd be tempted to start with the latter, unless you've got some strict computational limits to inference speed.

For your images, I'd start by creating a directory of JPEG images.  The most "official" way to handle them would be the process in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075319/how-do-you-load-label-and-feed-jpeg-data-into-tensorflow).

Comment: This answer is amazing, thank you so much! I already thought the basic MNIST model wouldn't work quite as well so my plan was to make sure i can import my images into my code and then do a whole lot of testing with the documentation to get a feel for all the different options. Not the most efficient way to do it but I'm trying to learn so this'll make me try out lots of things and find my way by trial and error. I've already looked into the Mobilenet network which already caught my interest, I'll look into using transfer learning to use it for the tokens.